# Python: alternative way of reinitialize lists in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In below code I would like to find an alternative way of reinitializing lists.

iter_obj_main has over 200000 iter_obj and 1 iter_obj has over 1 million rows of data and over 50 columns. (in below example I use just 3 columns a[], b [], c[] for demonstration)
This makes code look very long and ugly.

I am actually looking to empty all 50 lists after every loop?

Any suggestion python gurus?

```
i = 0
    for iter_obj in iter_obj_main:
       for x in iter_obj:
        i += 1
        a,b,c = ([] for j in range(3))
        if x == sometest:
            a.insert(i,x[0])
        else:
            a.insert(i,'')

        if x == sometest:
            b.insert(i,x[1])
        else:
            b.insert(i,'')

        if x == sometest:
            c.insert(i,x[2])
        else:
            c.insert(i,'')
        # moving data to database because of memory limitations and clearing lists.
```

Comment: Please add reason why you need to separate a,b,c -- why just not use the 'x' directly? 
-- like 'add_to_database( x[0], x[1], x[2] )' ?

Comment: Can you give us more insight on what your code is doing ? I think you should have another loop to iterate through the columns or your iter_obj. Also what's the point of initializing a to [] if you directly write over it with a = x[0] ?

Comment: The question is how do you use a,b,c... later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe use:

```py
for iter_obj in iter_obj_main:
    for x in iter_obj:
        a, b, c, *_ = x
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning twice to the same variable is a waste of time. There is no use in doing `a = []` when you follow it by another assignment `a = x[0]`.

Secondly, if `x` is always a list with 3 values, you could unpack it immediately:

```
for iter_obj in iter_obj_main:
   for a, b, c in iter_obj:
       # write to the database
```

Now the writing to the database would be the bottleneck anyway, so the above optimisation is not going to make it run significantly faster. You should focus on how you can write bulk data to your database without having to send instructions one-by-one.

Secondly, if your database table has 50 columns, it is very likely you have a design flaw in your database schema. It is very likely you didn't normalise it.

Comment: It's not an answer, the OP has 50 columns (a,b,c,d ...) and he doesn't want to hardcode all variables.

Comment: I added a paragraph to my answer. But the asker is not asking on how to use `a`, `b`, `c`. They presented specific code where they look for optimisation, and this answer tackles that and at the same time points out that this is not the bottleneck.